# MPI reduce optimisation

Tags: mpi

I have a rather simple MPI program where each node does a calculation and in the end I need the sum of of all the calculations. Each node has no need to communicate anything else than the final sum each node has calculated.

Currently this is what I am doing and it is working.

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);               // start up "virtual machine"
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);    // get size of VM
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);   // get own rank in VM

int localsum[1] = {0};
int globalsum[1] = {0};


for (i = lower+id; i <= upper; i=i+p) {
    localsum[0] = localsum[0] + getResult(i);
}

MPI_Reduce(localsum,globalsum,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(id==0)
{
    printf("globalsum1 = %d \n",globalsum[0]);
}
```

So each node skips every `size-of-vm` element in each loop iteration. However here's the problem. At any one time `getResult(i)` takes less time to compute than `getResult(i+1)`. This means that some nodes will have much bigger work load than others.

Is there anyway to balance this more out, or do something so nodes can steal work from other nodes when they are done?

Comment: That's a hard question to answer without seeing (or at least knowing) what's going on in `getresult()`. Can you tell us a little more about it or provide the code if it's short enough.

Comment: The whole program is doing euler totient sums. So getResult(i) sums the number of relative primes for i,x for all positive x where x<i. It's naively checking every single combination using Euclid's algorithm to check for the highest common factor. I know there are better ways to calculate this, but I am required to calculate it this way.

Answer (score 1):

As Wesley Bland points out in the comments, this is a hard question without knowing more about what `getResults()` does and how much time extra work we are talking about.

However, One suggestion I have is to pair expensive calls to `getResult()` with cheaper ones.

example: pair `getResult(lower)` with `getResult(upper)` & `getResult(lower+1)` with `getResult(upper-1)`

Sample loop (will need some modifications to fix some edge cases):

```
for (i = id; i <= (upper-lower)/2; i=i+p) {
    localsum[0] = localsum[0] + getResult(lower+i) + getResult(upper-i) ;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. That's indeed a good idea and will have a look at it. Although I was hoping there would be an inbuilt function in MPI to setup x tasks and that the processes could then grab tasks as needed or something along those lines. (Know that is possible in OpenMP using dynamic or guided scheduling). I've added a a comment to the original question about what getResult is doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not really the model that MPI operates under. There are other programming libraries/languages that have a tasking model, some of which are even built on top of MPI, but nothing that comes with MPI itself.

Comment: would there be anyway to calculate the perfect split? for any given i in the loop below we would call i-1 calls to hcf(highest common factor). So i=5 would make 4 hcf calls, 6 would make 5 etc.

Comment: also a little note. The pairing suggested didn't really optimise the runtimes for some reason.